# Unable to create a webservice only project with gvNIX/Roo

Tags: java, web-services, spring-roo, gvnix, gvnix-es

we are creating a web project (WAR packaging), which will only have webservices developed using gvNIX/Roo following a JAX-WS Java-first approach.

We are following the official guide available at http://www.gvnix.org/assets/doc/gvnix-1.4.1-reference-docs.pdf but it doesn't seem to work.

We have done the following steps:

1. Followed chapter 2, installation of gvNIX. Correct.
2. Followed chapter 3, development with Eclipse. We have used STS as distribution (chapter 3.1.1). Correct.
3. Followed chapter 5, create new application. Correct.
4. Followed chapter 30, add-on service.

   1. Followed chapter 30.2, creation of local services. Correct.
   2. Followed chapter 30.3, creation of servers from Java. Fail.

At this step 4.2 from chapter 30.3 it fails with the message:
"*Command 'remote service define ws --class ~.service.Service' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)*".

Putting it all together, this is the content of log.roo:

```
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev 8cb81a3] log opened at 2015-03-26 09:24:15
project --topLevelPackage com.test.webservices --projectName webservices --java 7 --packaging WAR
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev 8cb81a3] log closed at 2015-03-26 09:24:24
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev 8cb81a3] log opened at 2015-03-26 09:24:31
remote service class --class ~.service.Service
remote service operation --name myMethod --service ~.service.Service --return java.lang.Long --paramNames param1,param2 --paramTypes "java.lang.String,java.util.List"
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev 8cb81a3] log closed at 2015-03-26 09:30:59
```

And this is the command that doesn't work:

```
remote service define ws --class ~.service.Service
```

Why is this last command not working when you are following the official guide step by step?

Is it a bug on gvNIX/Roo?
Doesn't gvNIX/Roo support Java first approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you initialize the web support? Try to execute `web mvc setup`.

Comment: Hi, if we execute "web mvc setup" it creates 58 new files, 56 of them are absolutely unneeded in a webservice only project because they belong to the view and we will have no view at all.

Comment: You are right, a lot of unneeded files will be generated, but, by now, that's the way to configure web layer on the project and web services are generated on top of this. Any way, after you get working your service, you can clean what you don't need from project.

Comment: OK, where should I file a bug report? I have found Jira from Spring Roo but not Jira for gvNIX.

Comment: Nevermind, I've found it.

Comment: This is an Spring Roo issue, so I've just create the following JIRA Ticket to solve it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3637

Answer (score 0):

This error was fixed on gvNIX 2.0.0.M1

https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix

Try it and provide your feedback!

Best Regards